# Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower() even if mbstring is enabled

Tags: php, multibyte

I have just done an Os reload of my server and i've restored every thing and all data is correct but I am getting this:

> Fatal error: Call to undefined function mb_strtolower()

I have done some searching around and I have found that its the mbstring exstention for php not being installed, that doesn't seem to be my case as i've checked and its installed and enabled for all phpversion.

Anyone got any ideas?

Answer (score 33):

If you really have to use mb_-functions, you have to check if the [multibyte string extension](http://php.net/manual/en/book.mbstring.php) is installed on your system.

**Check** if the extension is installed?

```
<?php phpinfo(); ?>
```

Extension is not displayed?

**Install** the extension:

But therefore you have to reveal on which OS your PHP is running. So for example, in Ubuntu this can be achieved by running one of the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get install php-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.0-mbstring
sudo apt-get install php7.1-mbstring
```

Of course, this depends on the installed version of PHP.

**Don´t forget** to restart PHP after the extension was installed.

Comment: thanks the issue i had was i hadn't restarted apache -_- thakns for the help

Comment: On AWS instance it works with "yum install php73-mbstring"

Comment: this worked like a charm. thank you. I just had to modify the package names for php 8 to "apt-get install php8.0-mbstring"